# How to use a modem as both Ethernet and wifi

Tags: wifi-configuration

I have a ZTE ZXDSL 531B Modem and i want to use it as both a WiFi router and a modem i.e I want to use it with my PC with Ethernet but also use its WiFi for my cell Phone.I have a Cable - Broadband Internet Connection. Please tell me,how to do it.

my computer's IP address is 172.25.8.xx (my ISP gave me)

I tried to configure the router from 192.168.1.1 but it didn't work. so please help me with some details.

thanks in advance

Comment: I logged in to ZTE router setup page. and in Advanced setup I choosed PPoE and entered my Username and Password that my ISP gave me. but in case of IP when I entered my default IP 172.25.8.xx then my computer internet connection turned off showing an IP clash. in Router settings what should I enter as my IP ??

Comment: Are you sure the 172.25.8.x address is what your ISP gave to you? The 172. range is reserved for private networks and an ISP won't give this to you to access the Internet (your public IP)... Unless you're on a special network configuration...

Comment: yes I am on a Special network configuration. It is a private network indeed. so I asked my ISP to come and configure my WiFi but he is demanding a huge amount of money for that. so I started to configure it in my own knowledge. but as usual I know very little about Networking. 

is there any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Enter the PUBLIC IP you got from your ISP in the Router as WAN Adress
2. Configure your Router/Modem to act as a DHCP SERVER for LAN and WLAN
3. Setup your PC and Mobile Devices to use DHCP (DHCP/DNS both on automatic)

Also make shure your Router/Modem is built to do this (There are also Devices on the Market which are only Modem or Router and not both of them as you need it)

Comment: its mot working. when I entered my IP in Router's WAN address. then my computer is showing an IP clash..

Comment: then you have enterd a static IP on your PC and not DHCP as i said.

Comment: as I said earlier that I have a static IP address cause I am in a Private Network. so I can't enable my DHCP 

to access the Internet every time I have to enter that particular 172.25.xx.x IP as my default configuration otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

In the Control Panel, select the Network and Sharing Center. Click on the network connection and then click on the Details button. Put the address for the default gateway in your web browser to access the modem.